# What is the use of plist in IOS? How we can implement the plist?

Tags: ios, plist

What is the use of plist in iOS? How can we implement the plist? Can any one  please post some sample code for the plist because I am completely  new to ios development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plist is a lightweight file that is often used to save some data in iOS and OSX applications. It is just a key-value pairs of readable data.

Only `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` objects can be written to plist files. Those can then contain NSString objects (and other objects, like `NSDate` and `NSData`, etc), but what you're asking for is not possible

Please read this [Plist Guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html)